# JQuery FancyBox - displaying overwritten images

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox

I'm developing a user profile image control.  This control allows users to upload their own custom image for their profile which is displayed as a small thumbnail tucked away in the corner of the page. I'm using FancyBox to display the full size image.
Here's the problem, when a new image is uploaded, FancyBox shows the new image with the same dimensions as the original image!

This issue would not exist if each image upload would generate a new url but I'm getting my image url based on the user's ID.  For example: url="../profileImages/user_3.jpg"
In other words, uploading a new profile image overwrites the current image.

For some of you experts out there, I've tried adding a query parameter to the url like: "../profileImages/user_3.jpg?value=123" and it does not work.

Without getting into all the code that I'm using, I've created a bare bones example that will demonstrate the problem fully.

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="../jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#example").fancybox() 
});
</script>
</head>
<body runat="server">
<div>
<a id="example" href="TestImg.jpg"><img alt="example" src="TestImgThumb.jpg" /></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

1. Create two images. preferably people so you can see the scale stretch issue more cleary.
   Make sure that the first image is noticeably larger than the first and name it: TestImg.jpg
2. Open the webpage in your browser and view the image through FancyBox.
3. Now remove the first image and rename the second (smaller) image to: TestImg.jpg
4. Open the webpage again to see the problem.  The image in the hyperlink will be normal but the image that the FancyBox renders is stretched to the dimensions of the original image.

If you need further clarification on anything, I'll be happy to oblige.

Comment: The images are cached but it wouldn't happen if you reload the page, would it?

Comment: With an image cache issue, the new uploaded image would never be shown because the browser see's the same url and shows the cached image.  That's not my issue because the new uploaded image IS shown but it is stretched to the original image's dimensions.

Comment: Does no one have an answer to this problem!!?

Answer (score 0):

I typically create a time date stamped image for the thumbnail.  eg, in your case, [UserId_yyyyMMdd_hh_mm_ss].jpg and then store that in my Database.  I'll also overwrite the original file on the file system so that you can manipulate that later, but the image that you want to serve up is the one that you have stored in the database with a unique name.

It appears that you want to avoid storing the image url (or the image) in the database, which is why you are having cache issues.  Using just the User Id is not a good idea for these sorts of images is not a good idea because you will run into cache issues.